# How to get consistent dtypes after to_csv and read_csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

**UPDATE**:

TomNash's answer solves the question as asked. However, attempting to use it in my real problem led to issues with quoted column names, issues when there was missing data, etc. To circumvent this I'm using CJR's suggestion in the comments to simply pickle my DataFrames.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW**:

I have a Panda's DataFrame in memory. I would like to be able to write it to file (using `to_csv`), then use `read_csv` to read the results into a new DataFrame. I would like the original DataFrame and the new "from file DataFrame" to have identical data types.

I've attempted to get this working by using the `quoting` and `quotechar` arguments for both `to_csv` and `read_csv`. However, this doesn't seem to do the trick.

I understand that for `read_csv` the `dtype` argument can be used to force data types, but this isn't practical for my use case (lots of auto-generated files used for regression testing).

Full example below.

`tmp.py`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from csv import QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
import sys

print('Python version information:')
print(sys.version)
print('Pandas version information:')
print(pd.__version__)

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', '100', 100], ['B', '200', 200]])
print('df1:')
print(df1.info())

df1.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False, quoting=QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,
           quotechar='"')

df2 = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', quoting=QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, quotechar='"')
print('df2:')
print(df2.info())
```

Output from running `tmp.py`:

```py
Python version information:
3.7.3 (default, Jun 11 2019, 01:11:15) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
Pandas version information:
0.24.2
df1:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null object
1    2 non-null object
2    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
None
df2:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null object
1    2 non-null float64
2    2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
None
```

1. Column 1: As expected, the dtype is `object` for both DataFrames.
2. Column 2: Unexpected behavior. For `df1` the dtype is `object`, while for `df2` the dtype is `float64`.
3. Column 3: Expected behavior. `df1` has dtype `int64` while `df2` has dtype `float64`. As the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#module-contents) describes, `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` "Instructs the reader to convert all non-quoted fields to type float."

The contents of `tmp.csv` are below. Notice that the second column **is quoted**, so I would expect `read_csv` to give me an object.

`tmp.csv`:

```
0,1,2
"A","100",100
"B","200",200
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can get the behavior that you want easily from a CSV. Serializing a dataframe with `cPickle` or `dill` would preserve that information - if you're just looking to regression test against a bunch of objects that might be easier than writing your own converter for `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: @CJR - thanks for your input! I'll definitely consider that. The downside to the pickling approach is version control and readability: it's nice to have plain text files in my repository to a) be able to `diff` files when the expected results change and b) be able to crack open the files with a text editor or spreadsheet program to take a quick peek.

Comment: @TomNash - `QUOTE_NONE` does not do what I want. The difference is that in `df2` both column 2 and 3 have dtypes of `int64` (as opposed to `float64`).

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't have any `float64` values in `df1.iloc[:,2]`, just `int64`. The behavior of `read_csv` will convert straight to `float64` for any numeric. The solution below will preserve datatypes between read/write which is I believe what you want.

Comment: @TomNash - your solution below solves my problem as asked. I am having to mess around with all my column names now being quoted and perform a replacement of the quote character on all columns with dtype of `object`, but I can write a simple wrapper to handle this. Since it's just for testing, I'm not upset about performance implications of doing all this replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `QUOTE_NONE` instead on the read, this preserves the datatypes between read/write.

**Using the original datset with `int64`:**

```py
import pandas as pd
from csv import QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, QUOTE_NONE
import sys

print('Python version information:')
print(sys.version)
print('Pandas version information:')
print(pd.__version__)

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', '100', 100], ['B', '200', 200]])
print('df1:')
print(df1.info())

df1.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False, quoting=QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, quotechar='"')

df2 = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', quoting=QUOTE_NONE).replace('"','', regex=True)
print('df2:')
print(df2.info())
```

Result:

```py
Python version information:
3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas version information:
0.24.2
df1:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null object
1    2 non-null object
2    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
None
df2:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null object
1    2 non-null object
2    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
None
```

**Using `float64` values in the input:**

```py
import pandas as pd
from csv import QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, QUOTE_NONE, QUOTE_MINIMAL
import sys

print('Python version information:')
print(sys.version)
print('Pandas version information:')
print(pd.__version__)

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', '100', 100.1], ['B', '200', 200.2]])
print('df1:')
print(df1.info())

df1.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False, quoting=QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, quotechar='"')

df2 = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', quoting=QUOTE_NONE).replace('"','', regex=True)
print('df2:')
print(df2.info())
```

Result:

```py
Python version information:
3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas version information:
0.24.2
df1:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null object
1    2 non-null object
2    2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
None
df2:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null object
1    2 non-null object
2    2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
None
```